# print user's crontab

Tags: macos, cron

How can I print out my crontab?  Under Linux this can be done using `crontab -l`, however, running `crontab -l` under Mac OS X produces no output whatsoever and exits cleanly.

Here's my crontab:

```
0 9,10,11,12 * * 1-6 /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/vimmaid.sh
0 9,10,11,12 1,28 1,3,5,7,9,11 * /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/yankmaid.sh
0 9,10,11,12 1,2,*0,*1 * * /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/cronman.sh
0 *1,*3,*5,*7,*9 * * * /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/syl.sh
```

Comment: Should work the same way on OS X. Do you have any entries in the crontab at all?

Comment: @patrix added my crontab to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy and pasted my crontab into a file called `~/.crontab` and ran `crontab ~/.crontab`; now when I run `crontab -l`, I get:

```
0 9,10,11,12 * * 1-6 /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/vimmaid.sh
0 9,10,11,12 1,28 1,3,5,7,9,11 * /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/yankmaid.sh
0 9,10,11,12 1,2,*0,*1 * * /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/cronman.sh
0 *1,*3,*5,*7,*9 * * * /Users/alexej.magura/scripts/syl.sh
```

Comment: So your problem is solved now?

Comment: @patrix, yup.  :D

Answer (score 3):

The command for Mac OS X and Linux are the same: `crontab -l`
This seems to indicate that the crontab is empty. Maybe edit the crontab with `crontab -e` and afterwards print out the crontab. Your changes should now be printed to console.

Comment: Your first sentence asked just for that. No?

Answer (score 1):

OS X doesn't use cron for very much (relying more on launchd) but any crontabs should be located in /usr/lib/cron/tabs/ and /etc/crontab

Comment: running `find /etc/ -name 'cron*'` returns zilch.

Comment: Are the tasks in your crontab actually being run?

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
cat /Volumes/usr/lib/cron/username
```